# Get difference between two dates in seconds using Time Series Expression Syntax in Azure Time Series Insights Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-timeseries-insights

I have an Event Hub that sends data to Time Series Insights, with the following message format:

```
{
  "deviceId" : "Device1",
  "time" : "2022-03-30T21:27:29Z"
}
```

I want to calculate the difference in seconds between the Event Hub **EnqueuedTimeUtc** property and **time** property.

I created a Time Series Insights with an Event Source without specifying the **Timestamp property name**, in that way in Time Series Insights our Timestamp ($ts) property will be the EnqueuedTimeUtc property of the Event.

[image]

Now with those two properties, using **TSX (Time Series Expression Language)**, I want to do something like this:

```
$event.$ts - $event.time.DateTime
```

The problem I'm facing is that the result of that operation returns a DateTime, but in Time Series Expression there isn't a function to convert DateTime to Seconds, or to Unix Timestamp. [Time Series Expresion Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/reference-time-series-expression-syntax#datetime-functions)

[image]

Is there a way of achieving this using Time Series Insights and TSX (Time Series Expression)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

TSI is an depreciated service in Azure and there are not much features (inbuilt functions) available in it to explore data. Therefore, I suggest you to use Azure Data Explorer to work with the Event Hub Data.

Azure Data Explorer provides inbuild `datetime_diff`  function which allows to calculate the period in many supported formats based on your requirement using simple Kusto Query Language.

`datetime_diff()`:  Calculates calendarian difference between two datetime values.

Syntax:

`datetime_diff(period,datetime_1,datetime_2)`

Example:
`second = datetime_diff('second',datetime(2017-10-30 23:00:10.100),datetime(2017-10-30 23:00:00.900))`